# Is there any "Brunnian-like" braid which is not a pure braid in $B_n$ with $n\geq 3$?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, braid-groups

A braid $\beta$ is called Brunnian if it satisfies

1. $\beta$ is a pure braid;
2. $\beta$ becomes a trivial braid after removing any of its strands.

Obviously in $B_2$, every braid satisfies condition 2. When $n\geq 3$, is there any braid that satisfy Condition 2 but not Condition 1?

Comment: No - just choose any two strings that cross each other and remove a different string.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I do not understand your comment... I was asking about existence of such a braid.

Comment: I know, and the answer is no. If the braid is not pure then there must be two strings that cross each other, so if you you remove a different string then those two strings will still cross each other, so the resulting braid is not trivial.